Styler object has no attribute style, runs line-by-line debug but fails without
My function takes a dataframe as input and apply colors to rows based on conditions (two functions).
def apply_color_to_report(self, report_df, timeout):
        """
        color dataframe based on column 'alarmColor' with styler
        return report_df Styler object
        """

        def highlight_rows(row):
            return [f"background-color: {row.loc["alarmColor"]}" for _ in row]

        def highlight_timeout(dt):
            now = datetime.now()
            return f"background-color: {'red' if dt < now - timedelta(hours=timeout) else None}"

        color_report_df = (
            report_df.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis=1)
            .applymap(highlight_timeout, subset=[f"timeStamp [{timeout} hr timeout]"])
            .hide(subset=["alarmColor"], axis="columns")
        )
        return color_report_df

The script failed to execute without line-by-line execution in debug mode.
In debug mode, I made sure report_df is a dataframe and has attribute style. enter image description here
Also, if I put a breakpoint right before style.apply, go to debug terminal, and run the following block of code where colors are applied, it is completely fine and can even export an excel file based on the resulting Styler object.
enter image description here
But python just give up when I run it without line-by-line execution.
enter image description here
It keeps identifying report_df as a Styler object, which it should be a dataframe. Somehow report_df got converted to a Styler when I just run the script.
IDE: VSCode
Python: 3.12.3 virtual environment
pandas: 2.2.2
jinja2: 3.1.3


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Upon investigation, it resulted from calling the function twice. Problem solved.
